# 1080p movies won't play on my PC laptop

Tags: itunes, windows

Is there a problem with the specs on the iTunes help page regarding [1080p requirements](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3209)?

I have Windows 7 64-bit, an i7 quad-core, iTunes 10.7, 16 GB of RAM, NVIDIA GT 540M 2GB, and a 1080p display.

iTunes refuses to play these videos, giving this error:

[image: Screenshot]

However, QuickTime will play the videos just fine if I browse and open them myself. So I know its not a hardware problem.

Comment: I suspect that iTunes may have been corrupted, especially considering the strange logo shown in the above dialogue box. Have you tried reinstalling iTunes?

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX ~ Yes, the logo stays the same. I believe that is rather related to the system DPI setting.